# How many different ways can a student check off one answer to each question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, conditional-probability

If a multiple-choice test consists of 6 questions each with 4 possible answers of which only 1 is correct, In how many different ways can a student check off one answer to each question ?

Comment: What have you tried? How far have you gotten? What have you learned about combinatorics so far?

Comment: $4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4\cdot4=4^6$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is four times itself six times, $4^6=4096$.